# Citation replaced by question marks, no error or warning

Tags: natbib

In a pdf with many citations, one of them becomes ????, without errors or warnings. How to make it display correctly? Multiple compilation runs do not help.

Replacing the bibtex entry for that citation by an alternative one, the problem disappears. The entry appears correctly formatted, but maybe I missed something - see MWE of tex and bib files below. 
In the bib file, the citation that is commented out works, the other does not, when the bib file is used with the tex file.

tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{natbib}

\title{titl} 

\author{auth}

\date{dat}

\begin{document}

\cite{meier+schipper2012} \cite{mengel+2011}

\bibliographystyle{econometrica}

\bibliography{MWEbib}

\end{document}
```

bib file:

```
%@techreport{meier+schipper2012,
%  title={Bayesian games with unawareness and unawareness perfection},
%  author={Martin Meier and Burkhard C. Schipper},
%  institution={SSRN},
%  number={2055026},
%  year={2012}
%}

@article{meier+schipper2012,
  title={Bayesian games with unawareness and unawareness perfection},
  author={Martin Meier and Burkhard C. Schipper},
  journal={Economic Theory},
  pages={1--31},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@TechReport{mengel+2011,
  author={Friederike Mengel and Elias Tsakas and Alexander Vostroknutov},
  title={Decision making with imperfect knowledge of the state space},
  year={2011},
  month={2},
  institution={Maastricht University},
  address={PO Box 616, Maastricht 6200 MD, the Netherlands}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The "standard" bibliography style that emulates the style of the journal *Econometrica* is called `ecta.bst`, *not* `econometrica.bst`. (The file `econometrica.bst` does not seem to be part of the TeXLive distribution, whereas `ecta.bst` *is* included.) When I re-run your MWE with the bibliography style `ecta`, I get no problems at all. Which TeX distribution (and which vintage) do you employ? Do you know where you obtained the file `econometrica.bst` from?

Comment: `ecta` does not work when I try it. I have always used `econometrica` and had no such problems. Other citations display correctly.

Comment: @mico The `econometrica.bst` was recently removed from TeX Live due to an unclear license, but is, e.g. in TL2012.

Comment: @SanderHeinsalu - Please be a bit more specific about what happens in the "does not work" scenario.

Comment: MikTeX 2.8 with TeXnicCenter. No idea where I got the `econometrica` style from. I have used it for years.

Comment: @Mico - "does not work" means the problem is unchanged: I get ???? instead of the citation.

Comment: @SanderHeinsalu Both of your `.bib` entries work for me.  Are you sure they don't have duplicate keys in your `.bib` file?

Comment: you imply that only one reference doesn't get resolved.  could you add another reference to your `mwe.bib` file so there's something to compare, please.  the problem may be in an earlier reference, not in this one.

Comment: @AlanMunn - no duplicate keys.

Comment: @SanderHeinsalu As a follow-up to barbara's excellent comment, what does the `.blg` or the console log file show?

Comment: I suspect that you have an entry in your `.bib` file that is *missing* a year.

Comment: @AlanMunn - The MWE bib file isn't missing a year and the citation is replaced by ???? in it. There are no errors or warnings in the log file, do you want the whole log?

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I added another reference to the MWE, the problem persists.

Comment: @SanderHeinsalu Well, not for me. (So I can't reproduce your problem from your MWE).  This implies perhaps that you have an old version of something, probably `natbib` (since your MikTeX is quite old).  Add `\listfiles` to your document and what does it return for `natbib`?  I have `natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b`.

Comment: @AlanMunn - `natbib 2009/11/07 8.31a (PWD, AO)` in the log file. Time to update my whole TeX apparatus I guess.